# How to make webrtc ios work with ipv6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, ipv6, p2p

I'm using **WebRTC.framework** for iOS. When my iPhone is in IPv6 network, I can't see video stream from anyone, not even from those who are in IPv6 network. WebRTC is working between desktop clients that are in IPv6 network; even if one is in IPv4 network, everything is working. Android client is also working. I tried to change constraints:

```
 RTCMediaConstraints* constraints =
  [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc]
   initWithMandatoryConstraints:@{@"googIPv6" : @"true"}
   optionalConstraints:optionalConstraints];
```

but it didn't help. Also we turned on the `googIPv6` parameter on server.